# How to use an existing authentication database in source manager

Tags: qgis, authentication

I have an existing authentication db that the layers use when loading the project but when I try and add a layer using the source manager it does not seem to know about it and insists that I create a new one.  Put another way there was nothing listed under the Authentication configurations, when I filled out the basic tab it asked me if I wanted to save the configuration.

I assume I am missing something or does the source manager not use the new auth db?